# How did my company build a program on top of Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

My company hired an outside firm to build a complex program for them through Microsoft Access. The program is designed to link with a second access database, run a series of linear equations in the background, and spit out a few reports. As a user, I interface with a simple GUI in the Access file to 1) tell it which database to link with, 2) manipulate some data, and 3) run reports.

If possible, I would like to see the back end of this program to see the programming logic and to identify how it creates the reports. I am familiar with the basics and the methodologies of Microsoft Access, but don't know much about the dedicated functions of the application.

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Open Access - then ALT+F11 to open VBA editor.

Comment: If the GUI has an mde or accde file extension, you will not be able to view VBA code. You will need the original mdb or accdb file.

Answer (score 0):

The Access / GUI file is actually the front-end, whilst the database you select in the GUI will be the particular back-end you're dealing with. The coding is most likely to be in the front-end as VBA (or as a series of queries, macros & reports).

So, try holding shift when you double-click the Access file, which will try to load the GUI in "design" mode. As @June7 noted though, if its a locked-down / executable mde or accde this won't work, it'll need to be mdb or accdb. You'll also require a full version of MS Access, not just the free runtime installed on your machine.

If you manage to open in design mode, you should be able to see any tables, queries, forms, reports & VBA modules in the navigation pane on the left of the screen... unless of course, they've made them hidden objects. The can be unhidden if this is the case, though.

There may also be password-protection on some parts (which is easily crackable using info you'll find on Google).